# Float:right on outlook responsive code

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I'm coding a "responsive" email.

I have a table with 2 td's. An I want that the second one is on the right of the table.

[image: Sample]

The problem is that the first one can't have fixed width so the table can be responsive.

I tried the "float: worksright" solution but it doesn't work on outlook. (I have tried others but it was the better solution.)
Do you have any idea?

```html
<table style="max-width:600;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
             <td width="131" style="padding:25px 0;"><img src="images/autodesk.jpg" style="display:block; height:auto; max-width:131px; width: 100%;"></td>
                <td width="25" style="font-size:1px; padding:25px 0;">&nbsp;</td>
             <td style="padding:25px 0; vertical-align:top;"><table style="max-width:444;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                 <tr>
                     <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
                         <strong style="color:#ff9933; font-size:11px; text-transform:uppercase;">Autodesk</strong><br/>
                            <strong style="color:#020a0d; font-size:20px; line-height:27px;">Coleções de indústrias Autodesk</strong><br/>
                            <br/>
                            O Kaspersky Anti-Virus proporciona a primeira linha de defesa do seu PC contra vírus através de tecnologias antimalware premiadas, spyware e muito mais. Obtenha proteção real contra os programas maliciosos.<br/>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="max-width:444;">
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                             <div style="background-color:#ff9933; color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-transform:lowercase; padding:5px;">Saber +</div>
                           </tr>
                        </table></td>
                   </tr>
                </table></td>
           </tr>
  </table>
```

STOP EVERYTHING! I declare myself publicly a stupid person. It just use align="right" in parent table. --' Sometimes we forget the simplest things.

Thank everybody for your help. :)

Comment: Thanks for your correction Afsar. I'm an awful english speaker.

Comment: your mark up is a bit crowded and hard to read
try to put all of your css script inside <style> tags
also its better to use divs instead of tables

Comment: your image is broken

Comment: No it isnt'. It's about the Kaspersky Antivirus.

Comment: for outlook your better of using inline styles as class names usually get removed and the css which was associated with it wont be any more. Have you tried using percentages as width.

Comment: well then, I still suggest switching to divs instead of table. tables layout is very strict and may be a bit hard to work with.

Comment: You want that orange button to be on right side ?

Comment: @HussainAlmomen the better way to code to emails is use tables with inline style.

Comment: Yes @Afsar That is my goal.

Comment: @HussainAlmomen I've tried using divs in email, unfortunately it doesn't work. Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 don't support float, so your divs will always appear underneath one another, rather than next to one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set   `width="100%"` to table inside second td

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9usb4az/)